# Angular Text Does Not Show

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm writing a code where a user can select "Yes" or "No" in a field. It does not give any errors but, on the screen I can not see "Yes" or "No" options. What could be the problem in my code?

[image]

HTML:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex class="pr-4">
                <mat-label>Numune Toplanacak</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="CollectMaterialSample" [compareWith]="compareBasic">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of yesNo" [value]="prm.Id">
                        {{prm.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
yesNo: IBasicModel[] = [
        { Id: 1, Name: "Evet" },
        { Id: 0, Name: "Hayır" },
    ];

        CollectMaterialSample: new FormControl(this.product.CollectMaterialSample, Validators.required),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, `{{prm.name}}` should be `{{prm.Name}}` (uppercase N)